# How to print text in select query instead of NULL value in DATE field in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, case

I have a table `test` as follows :

```
create table test (id int, enroll date)
```

I have inserted some rows as follows :

```
insert into test values (1,'2012-01-02');
insert into test(id) values (2);
```

Now I want to select all rows and want to print 'Error' where the `enroll` field that has `date` datatype has `NULL` values.
I wrote the following query which gives me error :

```
select case when enroll is null then 'Error' else enroll end as Enroll from test;
```

My desired output is :

```
2012-01-02
Error
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it to string first. Check the below query;

```
select coalesce(to_char(enroll, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'Error') as formatted from test;
```